# Can I render a Nunjucks Template inside an 11ty shortcode?

Tags: javascript, nunjucks, eleventy

I have a Nunjucks shortcode in an Eleventy project. It's added to configuration in `eleventy.js` with the Eleventy `addNunjucksAsyncShortcode` method. My shortcode has gotten extremely messy with complex HTML string literals, and I'd like to refactor it into using a Nunjucks template along with the logic in my shortcode Javascript file.

Is there any way I can include and render a Nunjucks template in my async shortcode, or to call a Nunjucks template with the async shortcode config (which I could then use to include methods from my Javascript logic file)? It seems like the Nunjucks object is a singleton, and I get errors trying to use it.

Comment: Is it possible to refactor your code to use [Nunjuck macros](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#macro) instead?

Comment: @Mendhak I ended up exploring a couple of approaches, and staying with string literals. You can use Nunjucks to programmatically compile templates, but you lose the data cascade and there's a lot of context 11ty provides the instance to recreate. You can use 11ty programmatically to compile a template but it's the same problem as with using Nunjucks directly. I ended up doing that a lot with Jest for tests, where I can feed dummy data just for the template.

I ended up just writing good tests for the shortcodes - not ideal since no code completeion in string literals.